# How do you get the owner's public key of an ATA?

Tags: web3.js

How do you get the owner's public key of an associated token account using web3.js?

On SolScan, it very clearly displays it.

https://solscan.io/account/5StXNPyFF9UugaCodSqcAU6wcUpZSkgPNMHRJYffqL6w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use @solana/spl-token there is a method to pass in a token account ID and then you can check the owner field on it. Here is the code snipper from @solana/spl-token@.2.0

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/state/account.ts#L85-L103

Comment: Such a brain dead moment for me. Didn't even think to use the spl library. Thank you!